# Detect which direction the camera is facing?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to detect if the camera if facing Left/Right/Forward/Back. I have started with a script but it only points to the right side. How do I determine the axis at which the camera faces?

```
void Update () 
    {
        Vector3 dir = Camera.main.transform.forward;
        float absX = Mathf.Abs (dir.x);
        float absY = Mathf.Abs (dir.y);
        float absZ = Mathf.Abs (dir.z);

        if (absX > absY && absX > absZ) 
        {
            if (absX > 0f)
            {
                Debug.Log("RIGHT");
            }
            
            else 
            {
                Debug.Log("LEFT");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well an [**absolute** value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) in mathematics and used by you in

```
absX = Mathf.Abs (dir.x);
```

will **always** be a **positive** value.

What you rather want to use would be the original `dir.x`

```
// in general you should not use Camera.main repeatedly!
// if possible already reference it here
[SerializeField] private Camera _camera;

// Otherwise get it ONCE on runtime
private void Awake()
{
    if(!_camera) _camera = Camera.main;
}

void Update () 
{
    Vector3 dir = _camera.transform.forward;
    float absX = Mathf.Abs (dir.x);
    float absY = Mathf.Abs (dir.y);
    float absZ = Mathf.Abs (dir.z);

    if (absX > absY && absX > absZ) 
    {
        if (dir.x >= 0f)
        {
            Debug.Log("RIGHT");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("LEFT");
        }
    } 
    else if(absY > absZ) // absY > abs X is already implicit
    {
        if (dir.y >= 0f)
        {
            Debug.Log("UP");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("DOWN");
        }
    }
    else // both absZ > absY && absZ > absX are implicit
    {
        if (dir.z >= 0f)
        {
            Debug.Log("FORWARD");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("BACKWARD");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! It works. Is this the same way I should calculate forward and back? I was not able to achieve it.

Comment: @Saif I added it anway ;)

Comment: @Saif please be sure to accept the answer if it helped you. [See this for more information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)